# How to get data from a Global Set in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, globals

I have a Global Set called "Settings" (handle = 'settings'); Within that I have a text field called "Address" (handle = 'address').

I have a function in my Plugin and I'd like to get the Address data.

In the front-end I would write this:

```
{{ settings.address }}
```

How can I get the same information in my plugin with PHP?

I've got as far as this:

```php
$address = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::GlobalSet);
```

When I var_dump this array, I can see the address string. But I can't figure out how to filter down to the address correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the GlobalsService service available with `craft()->globals` like so:

```php
// Get the settings global set
$settings = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('settings');

// Access the address field
var_dump($settings->address)
```

Or you could use ElementCriteria as you suggested:

```php
// Get the GlobalSet element critera
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::GlobalSet);
// Set the handle you want
$criteria->handle = 'settings';
// Find the settings set
$settings = $criteria->first();

// Access the address field
var_dump($settings->address)
```

You can access all fields on the `$settings` variable using this synthax.

Mario

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer Mario. They both worked like a charm. I think I'll use use your first suggestion though... as it's more tidy and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get all values from a global set without having to specify each field handle you can do something like this:

```
$set = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('globalHandleHere');
$fieldLayoutFields = $set->getFieldLayout()->getFields();

foreach ($fieldLayoutFields as $fieldLayoutField) {
    $field = craft()->fields->getFieldById($fieldLayoutField->fieldId);   
    $value = $set->getContent()[$field->handle];

    // Do whatever with $value here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ragnarsson for adding a good answer to an older post. I can see this being useful for something I'm working on right now oddly enough. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help Mark. Remember that depending on the fieldtypes in the global you might have to extend this code. The code above would return null for assets for example. You might want to switch over the $field->type and write code that can handle all expected types.